# Why is my system image not showed in my app at runtime?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using Xcode 11, swift 4 and iOs 11.4
With the latest 11.0 Xcode version, we now have possibility to use native system icons (finally..)

I created a button with a system image, the "+". It does appears in my instantBuilder Xcode but when I run my app, the button is visible, but not the image

[image: list image]
[image]
[image: ![runtime view]

Any idea what I might have done bad ?

Comment: On what version of iOS are you running the app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use `SFSymbols` natively in iOS versions prior to iOS 13.
As specified in the [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sf-symbols/overview/):

> You can use SF Symbols in apps running in iOS 13 and later, watchOS 6
>   and later, and tvOS 13 and later. To browse the full set of symbols,
>   download the SF Symbols app.